# Google chrome about:#######?

Tags: browser

I have seen that typing **about:somekeywords** in browsers address bar gives some information. What is this ? Why ?
Do we have something similar for the Firefox, IE also ?

Example : Try below in chrome's address bar

```
about:histograms
```

Comment: This is actually an interesting topic of great interest to the Stack Overflow community. It is programming related as some of the tools made available aid debugging.

Comment: Sorry if i made it look like ambiguous, But still its interesting question which can help one understand how about:keyword can be utilized like developer. Please REOPEN this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It called "The [about: URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:)".

Answer (score 1):

It's a way for a browser to present 'about' style information.

And yes, we have it in all browsers. In a Mozilla based browser, try `about:mozilla`.

Comment: and certain versions of IE...

Answer (score 0):

yes. try about:blank

see [this](http://www.livinginternet.com/w/wa_browser_about.htm) for original mozilla about: commands
and entry on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 0):

Those are browser pages used for several different functions. Yes, IE and Firefox both have them, as well.

[Click here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/09/google-chromes-about-pages.html) for some information about Chrome's about pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just like "http:...", "ftp:.." and so on, the "about:..." directive represent a so called "schema", a keyword that identifies some protocol.
In this case, the about schema is the protocol chrome (like any other major browsers) uses to access misc informations.

Answer (score 0):

[About uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme):

`about:` is an internal URI scheme (also known as a "URL scheme" or, erroneously, "protocol") in various web browsers to display certain built-in functions. It is not an officially registered scheme, and has no standard syntax.

I simply love **about:robots**